# How to check whether a username is the same as something?

Tags: php

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $username == 'username') {
echo '<a class="Link" href="#">Upload</a>';
}
?>
```

This is supposed to check whether the user is logged in which it does then check whether the username is the same as a specific username and if it is echo out something which it doesn't which I don't know why any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Have you initialized the variable `$username` anywhere?

Comment: In PHP before 4.2.0, register_globals was turned On by default. So `$_SESSION['username']` was automatically extracted to `$username`. However, this was deemed to be a security hazard (and rightly so). So since then, you have to do that yourself. In your code you erroneously assume that `$username` exists because `$_SESSION['username']` exists. So instead, perform a `$_SESSION['username']=='username'` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you need

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] == 'username') {
echo '<a class="Link" href="#">Upload</a>';
}
?>
```